# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error on "python manage.py migrate contacts".

The error info does not pinpoint problem location.

Here is the error description:

http://dpaste.com/68162/

Hers is a sample model definition:

http://dpaste.com/68173/

Can someone point me to right direction???

I got this: http://blog.e-shell.org/66

but can not figure out the problem.

Comment: Are you sure this is the model causing the problem? It seems to be something to do with a ManyToMany relation, but there isn't one in the model you have pasted. Is there one somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the problem. There was this line:

```
note = GenericRelation('Comment', object_id_field='object_pk')
```

in model `Company` and `Person`. But `Comment` class was undefined. I commented the line at both places.  It works now.

Thanks for your time.